# How to return elements of a column in a dataframe/series that are less than a specific number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have a dataframe with 2 columns that I'm trying to get values that are less than 5. I'm trying to get pandas to return the values that are less than 5, but all I get in return are boolean values.

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 |

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
answer = data < 5
print(answer)
```

The result that I got :

```
       a     b
0      True  True
1      True  False
2      True  False
```

The result that I want :

```
1 2 3 4
```

I can't seem to find any function in pandas or numpy that can do this. I tried to access the values that are less than 5 one by one through the columns but it still returns boolean as well

```
a = data["a"]
b = data["b"]
answer_column_a = a < 5
answer_column_b = b < 5
print(answer_column_a)
print(answer_column_b)
```

The result that I got :

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: a, dtype: bool

0    True
1    False
2    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

The result that I want :

```
1 2 3
4
```

The only pandas function I know that deals with values from a specific column is loc and iloc, but both functions doesn't seem to be able to do conditionals. Are there functions out there that can do this? I only know numpy and pandas so far so I'm not knowledgeable enough to know if there are other Python packages that has a built in function that can do this. For Python, I understand you can get the values from conditionals through a code like for i in a or for i in b, but I don't know how to do that with pandas.

Comment: You're very close, just do `print(data[answer_column_a])` and `print(data[answer_column_b])`

Answer (score 0):

Use the underlying numpy array:

```
a = df.to_numpy().ravel('F')
out = a[a<5]
```

Output: `array([1, 2, 3, 4])`

Or using `stack`:

```
s = df.T.stack()
out = s[s<5].to_list()
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

To get the result per column, you could do:

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s[s<5].to_list()).to_list()
```

Output: `[[1, 2, 3], [4]]`